# Polar decomposition of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you prove that every matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ has a polar decomposition, i.e. can be written as $A=UP$, $U$ being unitary ($U^\ast U=UU^\ast=I$, with $U^\ast$ indicating the conjugate transpose of $U$) and $P$ positive semi-definite Hermitian? I have seen [this link on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition), but I am not convinced that $U$ is unitary, since if $U=AP^{-1}$, then:
$$UU^\ast=AP^{-1}(AP^{-1})^\ast=AP^{-1}(P^{-1})^\ast A^\ast,$$
which even swapping $^{-1}$ with $^\ast$ on $(P^{-1})^t$ doesn't seem to lead to the identity matrix $I$. Any suggestions on that?

P.S. Why does `[this link on Wikipedia](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)` not produce "this link on Wikipedia" with hyperlink to the given URL? Shouldn't it? *Because you must put http:// for it to work, or the link won't be parsed*.

P.P.S. I actually only need the statement for real-entry matrixes, i.e. $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $^\ast\leadsto^t$ and unitary$\leadsto$orthogonal, and Hermitian$\leadsto$symmetric.

Comment: Do you know about SVD decomposition? Are you sure it's not $A=PU$?

Comment: "SVD decomposition" is an example of RAS syndrome :). Anyway I have heard the name, only I don't have the proof of the existence of that decomposition in mind. And from the answer below, it _does_ seem it _is_ $A=UP$ as I said. Indeed, a professor told me $A=PU$, but maybe both can be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give here the real version of your equality. Notice that the matrix $A^tA$ is symmetric positive semi-definite then it's diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are non negative: 
$$A^tA=QDQ^{-1}$$
where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and we can define the square root of $A^tA$ denoted by $\sqrt{A^t A}$ by
$$\sqrt {A^tA}=Q\sqrt D Q^{-1}$$
where
$$D=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt\lambda_1,\ldots,\sqrt\lambda_n)$$
so let $P=\sqrt {A^tA}$ and $O=AP^{-1}$ then it's clear that $P$ is symmetric positive semi-definite and we have
$$O^tO=(P^{-1})^tA^tAP^{-1}=(P^{-1})^tP^2P^{-1}=I$$
so $O$ is orthogonal.

Comment: OK. Now of course you are implicitly saying $P^{-1}$ is also symmetric, as $(P^{-1})^tP^2P^{-1}=(P^{-1})^tP$, which can lead to $I$ only if $P^{-1}$ is symmetric. How do you prove $A^tA$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: $$\langle A^tA x,x\rangle=\langle A x,Ax\rangle=\|Ax\|^2\ge0$$

Comment: I guess the complex version is an obvious generalization. $A^\ast A$ is evidently Hermitian. How do you prove it is positive semi-definite in the complex case?

Comment: Do the same thing using the adjoint matrix.

Comment: OK let me explicit that for myself. $\langle x,y\rangle=x^\ast y$, so $$\langle A^\ast Ax,x\rangle=x^\ast A^\ast Ax=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\|Ax\|^2\geq0.$$ Remembering, naturally, that $(AB)^\ast=B^\ast A^\ast$, as used in the first passage and in the second. And P.S. adjoint matrix = conjugate transpose :). This comment is for myself, to explicit passages I don't regard as immediately obvious. No need for comments on this :).

Comment: Now $P^{-1}=(Q\sqrt{D}Q^{-1})^{-1}=Q(\sqrt{D})^{-1}Q^{-1}$, which transposes to $(Q^{-1})^t(\sqrt{D})^{-1}Q^t$, but the diagonalization uses an orthogonal $Q$ so $Q^{-1}=Q^t$ which transposes back to $Q$, and $Q^t=Q^{-1}$, getting that $P^{-1}$ is symmetric, and finally solving the last question left after this answer. Accepting in a second.

Comment: your answers do not address the case where P is not invertible though. One more line is needed to show ker(A)=ker(P)